# Profile picture changed automatically by itself

Tags: support, profile-picture

Suddenly, I found that my profile picture on all stackexchange websites changed to a random one I never used before.
[image]

I have always had this Gravatar one for ages.

Comment: I've linked the two together for now, since it's 99% possible it has the same cause. If the other question ends up being fixed and yours isn't, let me know.